# Data shouldn't change while clicking on both links on the same page in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know what to say or how to say about this issue. Apologies for not making any sense.

Actually, I want to show the data by clicking on different links with different data (different data is coming from different components `Posts` and `Album`) on the same page, but it's showing me the same data with different links.

The situation is going on when I click on `albumlink` posts data is changing which is not what I wanted.

For better clarification: You can check this [current situation what it going on](https://icecreamapps.com/v/fvcyd3z)
and **pls check the changing id of posts and album data on live example and video link**

Also this [example link](https://stacrtyrtyr)

Code snippets:

- Navbar.js:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navbar({ setPosts, setallAlbums }) {
    return (
        <>
            <li>
                <Link to="/">home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
                <Link
                    to="#postlink"
                    onClick={() => {
                        setPosts((shuffledPosts) => [
                            ...shuffledPosts,
                            shuffledPosts,
                        ]);
                    }}
                >
                    postlink
                </Link>
            </li>

            <br />
            <li>
                <Link
                    to="#albumlink"
                    onClick={() => {
                        setallAlbums((shuffledAlbums) => [
                            ...shuffledAlbums,
                            shuffledAlbums,
                        ]);
                    }}
                >
                    albumlink
                </Link>
            </li>
        </>
    );
}
```

- App.js:

```
import Posts from './pages/Posts';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { DataContext } from './context/DataContext.js';
import { useFetch } from './hook/useFetch';

export default function App() {
  const baseurl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  const { posts, setPosts } = useFetch(`${baseurl}/posts`, []);

  const { albums, setAlbums } = useFetch(`${baseurl}/albums`, []);

  return (
    <>
      <DataContext.Provider value={{ posts, setPosts, albums, setAlbums }}>
        <div>
          <Navbar setPosts={setPosts} setallAlbums={setAlbums} />
          <Posts />
        </div>
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

I couldn't understand what to do, what I'm missing, and what is wrong.

EDIT: I'm getting this warning now.

```
preview-c97e327a318ca.js:2  Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Album`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at Album (https://stackblitz-starters-gwe7dt.stackblitz.io/~/src/pages/Album.js:7:18)
    at App (https://stackblitz-starters-gwe7dt.stackblitz.io/~/src/App.js:14:57)
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: The reason for this is because you're using `<Posts />` component in your `App.js` File.

Comment: so what should I do? YES! I'm actually noticing that both component is triggered on the same page. is this possible to change the data on the page relying on both so that both should be visible while changing?

Comment: You need to learn how to use navigations using `react-router-dom`. Here, is one answer that will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router and ofcourse documentation is the best way to learn. Here is the tutorial section of docs: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#loading-data

Comment: ok i'll read it. but can you tell *is this possible to change the data on the page relying on both so that both should be visible while changing?*

Comment: What do you mean when you say: **so that both should be visible while changing**?

Comment: I mean like when I click on post link it should change and when I click on album link it own data should change not the post data and also both **postdata** and **albumdata** should visible on the same page when user clicks

Comment: Before that you need to be clear on what you want to achieve(your requirement)?

Comment: just like clicking on *postlink* the part of posts data should change and when clicking on *albumlink* then its part od data should change.  so both should change in it's own separate place

Comment: You mean when I click on *postlink* I should be navigated to **Posts** page(component) and when I click on **albumLink**, I should navigate to **Album** page(component) ryt?

Comment: yes, now you got the point. like you see in the video how i click on *postlink* so it's giving me posts data only likewise *albumlink* should give me album data, but data is changing at the same time. this can't be happen. it should change one by one

Comment: @user what you are trying to do is easily possible by using react components. Create a component that takes a list of posts as a prop and renders them. No state management here. Do the same for Albums as well. Then when using these components, pass the posts state in posts component and albums state in albums component. When one of them changes it will trigger their component to re-render showing you the updated values.

Comment: can anyone check the code what I'm doing wrong? for better information  pls check the **changing id of posts and album data**

Answer (score 0):

Your state management is correct, its only a matter of conditional rendering. This can be solved in two ways.

- Either add another state to tell the page which button you clicked
  and based on that state decide if you want to render Posts component
  or Albums component.
- Another method is when you get posts set albums
  to an empty list and vice versa all on the **context** level.

A sample of option 1 as requested: (Update your App.js to look like this)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Album from './pages/Album';
import Posts from './pages/Posts';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {DataContext} from './context/DataContext.js';
import {useFetch} from './hook/useFetch';

export default function App() {
  const baseurl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  const {posts, setPosts} = useFetch(`${baseurl}/posts`, []);

  const {albums, setAlbums} = useFetch(`${baseurl}/albums`, []);

  const [showPosts, setShowPosts] = useState(false);
  const [showAlbums, setShowAlbums] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <DataContext.Provider value={{posts, setPosts, albums, setAlbums}}>
        <div>
          <Navbar
            setPosts={values => {
              setPosts(values);
              setShowPosts(true);
              setShowAlbums(false);
            }}
            setallAlbums={values => {
              setAlbums(values);
              setShowAlbums(true);
              setShowPosts(false);
            }}
          />
          {showPosts && <Posts />}
          {showAlbums && <Album />}
        </div>
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: The ideal method is to disconnect the state management from your view components. Let the logic and state management happen in the parent component and any view components only take props and uses them..

Comment: can you pls give example for first option? yes, I deleted the context and try to share the state through components

Comment: but the problem still persists :(

Comment: @user I updated my answer to include a sample of method 1, this can definitely be improved but its a start.